# How can I check if variable in scanf is not number?

Tags: c

I have to prevent from putting letters into scanf in my program. I tried "isalpha" but is doesn't seems to work. Here is my code:

```
int main() 
{
    float T[100] = {0}; 
    float *pt=T;
    float suma = 0, zmienna;
    int rozmiar;

    printf("How many numbers would you like to put in: ");
    scanf("%d", &rozmiar);
    if (isalpha((char)rozmiar) != 0)
    {
        printf("Incorrect input");
        return 1;
    }
    else if(rozmiar>100)
    {
        printf("Incorrect input data");
        return 2;
    }
    else
    printf("\n Enter the number: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i<rozmiar; i++) 
    {
        scanf("%f", &zmienna);
        *(pt+i)=zmienna;
    }
}
```

Comment: check the return code from scanf. It will tell you how many items it processed. If it returns 0, it didn't put any numbers in your variable.

Comment: So instead of if (isalpha((char)rozmiar) != 0) , I just put if (rozmiar = 0)  ?

Comment: No... `int rc = scanf("%d", &rozmiar);`  Then `if (rc == 0) {` ...

Comment: @bruceg `if (scanf("%d", &rozmiar) != 1)` is better.  Consider end-of-file.

Comment: ice592, What do you want to happen to  non-numeric input?  It does not disappear when `scanf("%f", &zmienna);` fails to read it.

Comment: @chux it looks like the OP wants to exit the program if the first input is not numeric.  So, he doesn't have to worry about it sticking around in the input buffer.  If he were going to prompt again for valid input, he'd need to actually get the char data out of the buffer.

Comment: @bruceg Likely, yet the question addressed to ice592 is best answered by OP.  With your comment, more likely now OP will not engage.